# Kendo UI control not showing up on web page due to the same javaScript file being referenced, how to get past this?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have the following at the top of my page (call it page 2):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="abc" TagName="header" Src="../Header.ascx" %>
```

I have the following at the bottom of this page:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="../Scripts/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="../Scripts/NotificationsTreeView.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Both the /Header.ascx and the above page have this reference:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Kendo UI controls do not work if you reference the same file twice.

Given that these are two pages and both need `<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`, and I need to use the Header page on page 2, how would I get passed this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason not to keep jquery.min.js inside master page?

Comment: we're not using master pages :/

Comment: if the page itself has jquery.min.js, can't you just remove it from the control? the only downside to this is that every page that uses the control will also have to reference jquery.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know what I did but now it's working. The Register tag is on the page and both the register tag page and page 2 have the javaScript file referenced. Don't know...